# Database Design - User Table

Tags: database

I am designing a database that has these tables, user_accounts and user_info.

Here's the structure.

*USER_ACCOUNTS*

- user_id
- user_password
- user_type

*USER_INFO*

- user_id
- user_fullname
- user_address
- user_email
- user_contact_no

Now, my question is, is that design is okay? Somebody told me to merge them into one table. But can't fine the reason why I should merge it.

Any suggestions?

By the way, I'm designing it for authentication of users and for user's personal information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You could make that a flat table because the relationship is 1-1 (a user will never have more than 1 record in your user_info table). Nothing will be gained from this table relationship, in fact most queries will take more time because you have to look at two tables instead of one.

Comment: Yes, it's a 1-1 relationship. But the table name user_accounts is used only once when the user logged in to check it's user type. When I will access the user_info to query a user's fullname, I will not go to user_accounts first, but I can go directly to user_info.

Comment: This is true, but it won't save you too much. The overhead associated with the two extra columns (if you were to combine the tables into 1 table) is very minimal. There is more overhead in the future if you ever have to search both tables at the same time or do a lookup in the first table to get info from the second table or vice versa.

I don't think either is completely wrong or right, it depends more on style and how the tables are going to be used in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could merge them into one; it would make it more accessible. I do not really see why they need to be separate. Their account would hold their info.

Comment: what is the table name I am going to use sir?

Comment: @user1569143 Why not just call it "users" if you are doing one table. Short and makes sense, no unnecessary words are used in it.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting user information from account information is common, it mainly depends on your overall application. However, I'd recommend the USER_INFO table having a primary id too if you were using two tables, such as:

- USER_INFO

  - user_info_id (Primary Key)
  - user_id (Foreign Key for USER_ACCOUNTS)
  - etc

Questions with answers that are on this topic:

[Database design: 1 table or 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481155/database-design-1-table-or-2)

[MySQL: multiple tables or one table with many columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774715/mysql-multiple-tables-or-one-table-with-many-columns)

Comment: Thanks for the links. Can I ask, is it not good to have same primary keys in two tables?

Comment: Well - they wouldn't necessarily be the same if you are using auto increment on both.

Comment: I mean, if that's the case, I could add "user1" to user_info table and "user1" twice to user_info table?

Comment: Primary Keys should be integers, as it allows for fast queries on the index and minimal storage.

Answer (score 0):

I think merge is better option.
Number of row for both will remain same and so there is no question of redundant data.